# SQL Column ID value jumps 10000 times

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, primary-key

The ID column index jumps 10000 times.

> For example:

From  **index** :

- `5` goes to `10006`
- and the continues `10007` , `10008` , `10009`
- and then goes to `20003` , `20004` ....

How I could fix the ID values and put them in order again like before?

Also I have find something about a Reseed function, but I do not know what it is and how to use it?

Comment: Please provide some information about the Insert in the table.

Comment: This is a known and **intended** feature that normally occurs after an (improper) shutdown. An `IDENTITY` is an arbitrary number that is always ascending, nothing more, nothing less. Its actual value is meaningless other than that is is larger than the prior, and is therefore (along side a unique constraint) a good canditidate for a Primary Ket. You shouldn't "care" about what its actual value is.

Comment: If you really want a sequential number then use a `SEQUENCE` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Do you _really_ need a sequential number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using an identity column:

```
ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
```

There's no guarantee that this will remain in sequence. It was annoying when it first became more obvious (it didn't appear to happen in older versions of SQL Server but apparently could happen) but was also always by design. The skipping became very apparent when 2012 (?) was released. You're supposed to use a SEQUENCE now I believe if maintaining a steady sequence is required - e.g. invoice numbers:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62151/what-could-cause-an-auto-increment-primary-key-to-skip-numbers

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

It may also appear to skip if you perform an INSERT and it fails but this will only skip 1 typically. This has always happened and is by design - you need to reseed you identity to overcome this. Something like:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("dbo.MyTable", RESEED, 10)
```

Will make the next identity number 11 provided the other skipping doesn't also occur.

EDIT:
In relation to re-aligning your existing entries I'm no DB Expert but I did do this the other day on a table using a fairly rudimentary approach - but it's only a small table - there's probably a better way to do it:

```
BEGIN TRAN

--CREATE TEMP TABLE
DECLARE @Tooltip TABLE
(
    [TooltipId] INT NOT NULL,
    [TooltipKey] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)

--INSERT EXISTING INTO TEMP TABLE
INSERT INTO @Tooltip (TooltipKey, Name )
SELECT TooltipKey, Name
FROM dbo.Tooltip
ORDER BY TooltipId


--CLEAR ACTUAL TABLE
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Tooltip

--RESET IDENTITY TO 1
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("dbo.Tooltip", RESEED, 1)

--REINSERT FROM TEMP TABLE INTO ACTUAL TABLE
INSERT INTO dbo.Tooltip (TooltipKey, Name )
SELECT TooltipKey, Name
FROM @Tooltip
ORDER BY TooltipId

--TEST OUTPUT
SELECT * FROM dbo.Tooltip

--DO THIS FOR TESTING
ROLLBACK TRAN

--DO THIS WHEN YOU'RE CERTAIN YOU WANT TO PERFORM THE ACTION
--COMMIT TRAN
```

Bearing in mind that that if you have foreign keys or other references the truncate won't work and you'll have to do something more complex.Particularly if you have foreign keys referencing your existing incorrect IDs

Comment: How can I reseed the ID column from Management Studio?

Comment: Also could you explain me the DBCC CHECKIDENT ("dbo.MyTable", RESEED, 10) command , what it means and its parts? Thank you in advance

Comment: Also , how can I fix all the ID values and put them in order again from 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ....

Comment: The DBCC CHECKIDENT code will reseed the column - so if you need set it so that the next number is 6 do DBCC CHECKIDENT ("dbo.MyTable", RESEED, 6)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem.  This is a performance feature of SQL Server.

SQL Server is designed to handle many concurrent transactions -- think dozens or hundreds of inserts per second.  It can do this on systems with multiple processors.

In such an environment, "adding just 1" to the maximum can have a lot of overhead -- all the different processors have to agree on what the maximum is.  This involves complex locking or sequencing of the transactions -- which slows things down.

To prevent performance bottlenecks, SQL Server will sometimes pre-allocate identity values.  This can result in gaps if the numbers are not used.

If you don't like this feature, you can work around it by using a sequence and a trigger to assign the value.  Just be warned that alternative approaches have performance implications.

Answer (score 1):

Have you been running large deletes?

Delete doesn't reset the identity, so if you had rows 1-10000, then deleted all of them, the identity would still continue from 10001 when you added a new row.

Truncate does reset identity, but always DELETES ALL ROWS without logging.

You could use the reseed function to reset identity also, but wouldn't be helpful for this case since you'd slowly increment back into ids used by existing data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have not deleted anything , how I can reseed the ID column?

Comment: The function to reseed would be "DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[TestTable]', RESEED, 0)". Don't do it though - your table already has data.

The other answers already covered the alternate reasons for gaps in identity. If the numbering matters, use sequence data type.